# How to create a 3-d array from 1-d array?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, array-broadcasting

Let's say I have a 1d array

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
```

What's the best way to get the array b with shape (3, 4, 5) from a? Every value of the array a is used to initialize a 4x5 array and stacking all these arrays will create the array b. I was wondering if I could avoid looping to create the array b.

```
b = np.array([[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]], [[2, 2, 2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2]], [[3, 3, 3, 3, 3], [3, 3, 3, 3, 3], [3, 3, 3, 3, 3], [3, 3, 3, 3, 3]]])
```

Output for b:

```
array([[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]],
   [[2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
    [2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
    [2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
    [2, 2, 2, 2, 2]],
   [[3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
    [3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
    [3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
    [3, 3, 3, 3, 3]]])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve by creating an array of ones and multiplying it by `a[:,None,None]` to use broadcasting.

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
b = np.ones((3,4,5), dtype=int)*a[:,None,None]
```

You can also do this without creating an array of ones using [`np.broadcast_to`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast_to.html#numpy.broadcast_to).

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
b = np.broadcast_to(a[:,None,None], (3,4,5))
```

There should also be a way to do this using [`np.repeat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html). Currently, I only found a way that achieves the desired result using nested calls.

```py
b = np.repeat(np.repeat(a[:,None], 5, axis=1)[:,None], 4, axis=1)
```

Comment: The function broadcast_to is the fastest in my tests. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Use [`numpy.tile`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html):

```
b = np.tile(a[:, None, None], (1, 4, 5))
```

*NB. The `1` is for the unchanged existing dimension.*

Output:

```
array([[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]],

       [[2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
        [2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
        [2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
        [2, 2, 2, 2, 2]],

       [[3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
        [3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
        [3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
        [3, 3, 3, 3, 3]]])
```